# Second condition alternative for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop, conditional-statements

Is it possible to add a second condition to the [alternative for loop representation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) of Java.

I have a collection that is updated at the end of a `do-while` loop. In this `do-while loop`, there is a `for loop`.

E.g.: *(This doesn't work but illustrates what I'm trying to achieve)*

```
List<String> list =....load up with stuff

do {
    for (String string : list && counter < 5) 
    {
       System.out.println(string);
       counter++;
    }
while(update list)
```

Somehow the normal representation:

```
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() && counter < 5; i++)
    {
       System.out.println(list.get(i));
       counter++;
    }
while(update list)
```

Doesn't work in this construction.

### Update

I tried both answers with this piece of code:

```
      int counter = 0;

      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      list.add("a");
      list.add("b");
      list.add("c");
      list.add("d");
      list.add("e");

      System.out.println("Test one");

      for (String string : list) {
            if(counter < 3 )
                 System.out.println(string);
            else
                 break;
            counter++;
      }

      System.out.println("Test two");

      counter = 0;

      for (String string : list) {
          if (counter >= 3) break;
           System.out.println(string);
           counter++;
      }
```

[TedHopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/535871/ted-hopp)'s answer solved breaking out of the first loop.

### Final Solution

Breaking out of the `for loop` **and** out of the `while loop`, I ended up doing the following:

```
int breakNow = false;

do {
    for (String string : list) 
    {
       System.out.println(string);
       counter++;

       if (counter >= 3) 
       { 
           breakNow = true;
           break;
       }
    }
while(update list && !breakNow)
```

Comment: The collection that is updated.. Is it the list you are iterating through ?

Comment: I don't think you are allowed to modify a list when iterating over it. It results in the [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

Comment: @Adarsh: You are right, my construction is a bit different. Let me update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot incorporate a binary test with the enhanced `for` loop; it's not allowed by the syntax. You'll need to use the traditional `for` loop syntax, or else put the boolean test inside the loop and `break` out of it.

```
for (String string : list) {
   if (counter >= 5) break;
   System.out.println(string);
   counter++;
}
```

I'm not sure what wouldn't work with the traditional syntax that would work for the enhanced `for` loop; they essentially do the same thing. (In fact, since the enhanced `for` loop uses an iterator, you risk a concurrent modification exception if you are updating the list asynchronously.)

Comment: This solved it. Thanks. I already tried it with a `break` statement but I had my condition wrong. This clearifies it.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, but you could create something cool like this:

```
public class ForEachCondition
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(3);
        ints.add(100);
        ints.add(200);

        for (Integer i : new ConditionalIterator<Integer>(ints, new ConditionalIterator.Condition<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean next(Integer t)
            {
                return t < 130;
            }
        }))
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}

class ConditionalIterator<T> implements Iterable<T>, Iterator<T>
{

    private Condition<T> condition;
    private Iterator<T> iterator;
    private T next;

    public ConditionalIterator(Iterable<T> it, Condition<T> cond)
    {
        this.iterator = it.iterator();
        this.condition = cond;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator()
    {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            next = iterator.next();
            return condition.next(next);
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public T next()
    {
        return next;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove()
    {
        iterator.remove();
    }

    public static interface Condition<T>
    {
        public boolean next(T t);
    }
}
```

With the new Java 8, the for could look like this:

```
for (Integer i : new ConditionalIterator<Integer>(ints, (Integer t) -> t < 130)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: This is awesome and very creative! Thank you!